# Changing remote server URL

Tags: git, svn

Basically, when I am within the company's network, I have to switch the remote server's URL from something like:

`https://svn.companyurl.com:444`

to

`svn://192.168.1.143/path/to/repo`

This I guess has something to do with the way the network is set up.

The 2 URLs point to the same repository. They just differ from within the company's network and outside the company's network. What would be a good way to change these URLs and also to make sure that I don't have to begin again with linking the 2 repositories?

Comment: I've tried updating the hosts file, by adding a line like `https://svn.companyurl.com:444 svn://192.168.1.143/path/to/repo`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just declare two different remotes? When you're in the company's network push and pull to/from for example `office` remote, and when at home to `home` remote.

And to add a remote just run:

```
git remote add office svn://192.168.1.143/path/to/repo
```

EDIT:

Which is true for git but I've just realised you're actually usig `git-svn`. Try adding manually a new remote to the `git-svn` config. (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html#_configuration)

Comment: Doing this doesn't recognize the remote 'office' repo. If I execute `git svn fetch office`, the error I get is `[svn-remote "office"] unknown`

Comment: I've just noticed you're using git-svn. I've updated the answer, I hope it helps, though I haven't worked with git-svn before :/